# UWP How to Pause Audio Recording using AudioGraph API?

Tags: c#, uwp, audio-recording

I'm creating a UWP application that will record and play audio captured from a connected device.  I've used the AudioGraph API to this end.  The Play, Stop and Record methods are already finished.  I'm now seeking best way to allow the user to pause recording.

My current code is as follows:

```
private async void Stop()
    {
        EnableCommands(false);
        audioGraph?.Stop();
        await FinalizeOutputFile();
    }
```

Since I don't want to finalize my output file when the Pause button is pressed, what is the suggested approach to implementing this feature?

Comment: Why don't you use [`MediaCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture#capture-audio) to capture audio?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT isn’t that mainly geared toward camera usage?

Comment: It also could be use to audio capture.